# How to ORDER BY a column from INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, inner-join

Table structure from `comments`:

```
id | user_id | cmt_id | slug 
 1 |   565   |   5    | home
 2 |   324   |   6    | home
 3 |   71    |   7    | home
 4 |   408   |   1    | about
```

Table structure from `cmt_likes`:

```
id | user_id | cmt_id | slug 
 1 |   324   |   6    | home
 2 |   324   |   6    | home
 3 |   324   |   6    | home
 4 |   71    |   7    | home
 5 |   71    |   7    | home
```

As you can see on the table `cmt_likes`, on the `home` page the comment from the user `324` have 3 likes, and the comment from the user `71` have 2 likes (i use the number of rows, that have the same `cmt_id` and `slug` to count the likes).

This is my current sql, this is only for display the comments:

```
SELECT 
  `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`cmt`, `comments`.`cmt_id`, `comments`.`slug`, `users`.`username`
FROM `comments` 
  INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `comments`.`slug` = :slug
ORDER BY `comments`.`id` DESC
```

But i want to `ORDER BY` the number of likes.

so i tried:

```
SELECT 
  `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`cmt`, `comments`.`cmt_id`, `comments`.`slug`, `cmt_likes`.`cmt_id`, `users`.`username` 
FROM `comments` 
  INNER JOIN `users`
    ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
  INNER JOIN `cmt_likes` 
    ON `comments`.`cmt_id` = `cmt_likes`.`cmt_id` 
WHERE `comments`.`slug` = :slug
GROUP BY `cmt_likes`.`cmt_id` 
ORDER BY `cmt_likes`.`cmt_id` DESC
```

But this sql only return the rows that have 'likes'. If you look at my tables you will see that the comment from the user `565` don't have likes, so this row is not returning in the above sql.

This is my current result with the above sql:

```
324
71
```

And this is what i expected:

```
324
71
565
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `left join`s.  I also recommend table aliases:

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.cmt, c.cmt_id, c.slug, 
       c.cmt_id, u.username 
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_user = u.user_id LEFT JOIN
     cmt_likes cl
     ON c.cmt_id = cl.cmt_id 
WHERE c.slug = :slug
GROUP BY c.user_id, c.cmt, c.cmt_id, c.slug, c.cmt_id, u.username 
ORDER BY cl.cmt_id DESC
```

However, I think you also need aggregation before the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.cmt, c.cmt_id, c.slug, 
       c.cmt_id, u.username 
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_user = u.user_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cl.cmt_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM cmt_likes cl
      GROUP BY cl.cmt_id
     ) cl
     ON c.cmt_id = cl.cmt_id 
WHERE c.slug = :slug
GROUP BY c.user_id, c.cmt, c.cmt_id, c.slug, c.cmt_id, u.username 
ORDER BY cl.cmt_id DESC
```

Comment: Indeed, i only needed to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` in my second sql.